# Delete a Backup currently running in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I currently have a Backup job in progress in Azure...File and Folder level only. I need to stop the job it has been running for too long. How can I stop it.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is "Backup job"? Azure backup job?

Comment: Could you please provide more details and tell me what is ```Backup job```?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Storage (Azure Files), you can go to Azure Files > Backup > select the ... > Stop Backup.

[image]

You can also stop a backup job through Powershell.

```
Stop-AzureRmBackupJob
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.backup/stop-azurermbackupjob?view=azurermps-6.13.0

To stop backup on a VM, you can go to the vault item's dashboard and select one of the following:

**Stop protection and retain backup data.** This option will stop all future backup jobs from protecting your VM; however, Azure Backup service will retain the recovery points that have been backed up. You'll need to pay to keep the recovery points in the vault (see Azure Backup pricing for details). You'll be able to restore the VM if needed. If you decide to resume VM protection, then you can use Resume backup option.

**Stop protection and delete backup data.** This option will stop all future backup jobs from protecting your VM and delete all the recovery points. You won't be able to restore the VM nor use Resume backup option.